# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null not being registered by chrome (trying to appear and disappear the header)

Tags: javascript

IDK whats the problem but chrome is saying that the classist cannot be read even though I have everything set up exactly as the video portrayed it PS: I am beginner in Coding so IDK why it isn't being read by chrome.

What I was hoping to happen was add a header then make the header appear and disappear but it works perfectly on Codepen but not chrome can you explain why?

````
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var w = window;

  var prevScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
  var curScroll;
  var direction = 0;
  var prevDirection = 0;

  var Header = document.getElementById('site-header');

  var checkScroll = function() {

    /*
    ** Find the direction of scroll
    ** 0 - initial, 1 - up, 2 - down
    */

    curScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
    if (curScroll > prevScroll) { 
      //scrolled up
      direction = 2;
    }
    else if (curScroll < prevScroll) { 
      //scrolled down
      direction = 1;
    }

    if (direction !== prevDirection) {
      toggleHeader(direction, curScroll);
    }
    
    prevScroll = curScroll;
  };

  var toggleHeader = function(direction, curScroll) {
    if (direction === 2 && curScroll > 92) { 
      
      //replace 52 with the height of your header in px

      Header.classList.add("hide");
      prevDirection = direction;
    }
    else if (direction === 1) {
      Header.classList.remove("hide");
      prevDirection = direction;
    }
  };
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);

})();```
````

Comment: Where are you adding your script tag? Try moving it to just before the closing body tag `</body>`. This way we can ensure that the `#site-header` is loaded before we execute the script.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know it was that simple I guess I still have a lot to learn but we all start somewhere.